# Scheduling DevOps Query results on email

Tags: azure-devops, bug-tracking

The Requirement is that:
1. I have a Query created in my account in Azure DevOps which fetches me a list of all active work items in my current sprint. This is required for a regular followup with my team on a daily basis.
2. The work of extracting the list and sending it to my team as to be done manually.

Is there a way in which the Query saved in my DevOps account be executed on a scheduled basis (may be twice a day) and be sent over as an email to a pre-configured mailing list?

Any feature in DevOps or tool, if any, may be suggested. Thus avoiding the need to code using DevOps API for achieving the same.

Comment: Hi @Manish Scheduled Work Item Query extension mentioned by Krzysztof Madej seems to be what you were looking for. You can [accept below answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked out.

Comment: Hey Krzysztof, thanks for the response. I actually have used the abovesaid extension already, but the problem is it gives a pretty simple Table formatted results of the query in the email addresses provided. What i have been looking for is below:
1. A way in which it can be made presentable like a scheduled reporting task to the management
2. Customization in templates and pivots etc.
3. Separation of TO, CC & BCC addresses

I hope you get my point now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported out of the box. Please take a look on this [developer community topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365496/send-email-with-query-results-on-a-schedule.html). Reading the comments you may find this:

- extension: [Scheduled Work Item Query](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Quadrotech.ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery)
- code for above mention extension: [github](https://github.com/Quadrotech/ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery)

So this extension should give you what you want.

Comment: A newer version of the extension is available at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechFreak.TFADOScheduledWorkItemQuery